# Running several sites off the same code except a config

Tags: nginx

I have the same code which will be used for several sites. In the Nginx config I wanted to have all the sites point to the same code folder.

I think this should work. The only catch is that I want each site to use a different config file.

How could something like this be achieved? Surely I wouldn't need to duplicate all the websites code just to have each one have a different config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What language are you scripting in? Most languages will have a way to examine the incoming request. From this you could extract the domain name from the request and base which conf file you load based on the name using an if or switch statement.

You could also use a get variable for example www.domain.com/index.html?conf=conf1.conf. Then in your controller you'd need to look at that git variable to determine which conf file to load.

Either of these solutions should be easy to find in the docs for you scripting language.

Comment: Im coding in python. This sounds like it would have more overhead than symlinking the content to different directories.

Comment: symlinking would require having the different url's point at different directories (which would then be linked back to your real code directory). This would probably be a good way to do it as well.